# Why ArgoCD does not kustomize resources?

Tags: argocd, kustomize

I want to add **sync-wave** annotations using Kustomize and then deploy resources using ArgoCD.

I expect that ArgoCD will kustomize resources first and then apply them to a cluster.

However ArgoCD try to create (apply) the Kustomize resource itself in a cluster instead of kustomization the other resources.

Here is the file structure

```
├── kustomization.yaml
└── ns.yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: test
```

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ns.yaml
commonAnnotations:
  argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "-9999"
```

The namespace `test` is not being created. The `sync-wave` annotation is not added. Instead ArgoCD is waiting for a "resource" `kind: Kustomization` being created.

Why? How to fix this?

Comment: Hi, any chance you found the solution to your problem? I'm getting the same kind of errors and only finding this kind of unanswered questions.

Comment: Check which kustomize version are you running under the hood of ArgoCD. I got similar problem which was caused by old 4.5.7 version.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have directory recursion enabled in your Application manifest? That's my guess what is causing the issue. Try disabling directory recursion and it should work.